# How to serialize big string using messagepack in java?

Tags: java

I used msgpack-0.6.12 and javassist.jar jar files in my program.But I still not able to serialize string. So,help me find my mistake where I am wrong.

Here is my serialization code:

```
    MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();
    BufferPacker  packer = msgpack.createBufferPacker();
    // Serialize
    packer.write(src);//src is object of class where my string is defined.
    byte[] bytes = packer.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Please describe what goes wrong.

Comment: I want to serialize big string using messagepack. I used the above code for that but at the end (after serialization) , its size will become as it is. I didn't see any changes in size. what is missing in my code?